# QT Data storage and updating across multiple computers

Tags: c++, database, qt5

Im struggling to understand how to make an inventory application:

1. Store inventory data (item name, sku, descriptions, prices, inventory counts)
2. Allow computers access from different networks
3. Keep computers updated. By that I dont understand how they communicate to each other across different networks/connections, so that if one computer makes a change to say inventory count how does it let the other computers know to subtract say 5 of an item bc 5 were sold.

question 1 I can understand how storage works to a degree, but when it comes to 2 and 3 how would you approach it? I figured servers would be the answer but then the question becomes what kind? AWS RDS? If you have links to tutorials that can explain this process and different approaches please feel free to link

Ive been trying to figure this out for a few months now and I think im getting more confused than answers (I swear I get more inventory application ADs crap than actual information, like no joke try searching "how inventory applications store and update data and keep computers updated" or any phrase like that... and its a bazillion freaking ads lol)

Comment: what does it have to do with QT? BTW, don't you think this question belongs to some other discussion board, say, Software Engineering? Possibly [related](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/396116/turn-based-access-to-update-shared-resource-such-as-inventory)

Comment: Well bc im using QT to develop this application, and I already have a program that uses this data to do various things on a single computer. I just dont understand how to go about adapting it so that multiple instances of that application on different computers can do this concurrently

Comment: Sounds like you want a database. See the Qt SQL documentation; set up a database server on your desktop (that "server" there doesn't need to be a separate machine), and make your application talk to that. Then you have 1 and 2 and most of 3. Telling the (desktop) applications that inventory has changed on the (database) server is another thing; perhaps "message passing" is a search term you can use, or "publisher subscriber".

Comment: You will need a type of synchronization technique. 
If connectivity is not a problem, just connect application to the remote database. But if frequent disconnection is usual, it's a good idea to have local database that stores **changes**. Then you can apply changes to the remote DB.